# Error creating Date() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm totally new to **Javascript**, and I'm getting trouble creating a `Date` from `milliseconds`.

I have this code:

```
function (result) {

  alert("Retreived millis = " + result.created);
  //Prints "Retrieved millis = 1362927649000"

  var date = new Date(result.created);
  alert("Created Date = " + date);
  //Prints "Created Date = Invalid Date"

  var current = new Date();
  var currentDate = new Date(current.getTime());
  alert("Current Date = " + currentDate);
  //Prints "Current Date = Sun Apr 14 2013 12:56:51 GMT+0100"
}
```

The last alert proves that the creation of `Date` is working, but I don't understand why the first `Date` is not being created correctly, because the retrieved `millis` are correct... and as far as I understand in Javascript there're not datatypes, so it can't fail because the retrieved `millis` are a `string` or a `long`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `result.created` is a string. Since the `Date` constructor accepts strings but expects them to be in a different format than that, it fails. (E.g., `new Date("1362927649000")` results in an invalid date, but `new Date(1362927649000)` gives us `Sun Mar 10 2013 15:00:49 GMT+0000 (GMT)`.)

This should sort it (by converting to a number first, so the constructor knows it's dealing with milliseconds since The Epoch):

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(result.created, 10));
```

Comment: It solved the problem. I thought that Javascript wouldn't complain if you pass a integer or a string... As said I'm totally new to this... Thanx a lot!

Comment: @MikO: JavaScript will do a lot of automatic string-to-number conversions, but it just happens that the `Date` constructor accepts *either* a string or a number, and so it doesn't trigger the automatic conversion. Instead, it looks at what it has and branches, either parsing a string in a given format, or using the number. If a function *only* allows numbers, odds are high it'll happily auto-convert the string for you (`Math.max(10, "100")` returns `100`, for instance). Just not the `Date` constructor. :-)

Comment: OK, I clearly understand it now. Thanx very much for the solution and for the extra info.